# How to force Flutter to use new developer certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, flutter

I am currently developing an application with Flutter. I used to be able to run the code directly using VS code or the command `flutter run`. Ever since I revoked my developer certificate and generated a new one, the above options when executed, the app crashes on my iPhone. If, however, I run it on the simulator, it works as expected.

I suspect that this is due to the change in certificates. Xcode says my app is signed with the certificate B39****** where as `flutter run` says it is signing with 578*******

I have even tried `flutter config --clear-ios-signing-cert` as well as `flutter upgrade` and it still signs with 578.

How can I force flutter to sign my app with the new certificate? Currently, this means I cannot use the hot reload feature on my physical devices.

Comment: I have re-downloaded my project from GitHub and it seems to be working. I would still like to know a proper fix for the future though.

Comment: You could try to have opened your project with xcode and set the certificate there. I had a similar issue and once I opened it on xcode it fixed itself.

Comment: @Serl Thats what I thought I done. I revoked my certificate, downloaded the new ones from within Xcode, Selected personal team and then selected the main certificate again. That did not refresh it. I also tried to modify some other settings too.

Comment: That is weird indeed... glad you manage to get it to work by re-downloading it. Something xcode just needs a clean restart or something

Comment: @Serl maybe. I also tried `flutter clean` too incase there was a problem in the cache. That didn't even work.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you uninstall the version of the app signed by the previous cert on your iPhone?

Comment: @ReverseCold Yes I did.

Answer (score 9):

Run `flutter config` to see your current settings and a certificate choice applied.

To clear the choice according to the documentation you can run:

`flutter config --clear-ios-signing-cert`.

> --clear-ios-signing-cert                     Clear the saved development certificate choice used to sign apps for iOS device deployment.

Flutter 2.0.5.

Answer (score 5):

I think check this file `vim ~/.flutter_settings` will be well.

```sh
{
  "ios-signing-cert": "Apple Development: XXXX@gmail.com (XXXXXXXX)",
  "enable-macos-desktop": true
}
```

Comment: Where can is this file located (I suppose it's somewhere in the flutter sdk but I can't find it)

Comment: `~/.flutter_settings` doesn't exist on my system... Did it move? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue a couple months ago.  It took me several hours and basically I had to sign out of and then sign back into XCode:

XCode->Preferences->Accounts

Completely sign out of any accounts and then sign back in with the newest one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> flutter clean

in the terminal. When will clear the selected certificate and will present a choice to you next time you run you code

Answer (score 1):

In code sign page of Xcode.
There is sub pages, with tab: `All`, `Debug`, `Release` and `Profile`.
It takes me several days to figure out I have selected the wrong develop team.
And then takes me few hours to find out that I have somehow clicked the `Profile` tab, instead of `All`.

I guess you have the same problem.

Comment: I found this inside Xcode project file. I searched keword 'team'. Then I found three different place about code signing team.  And then I realized what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by going into Xcode and setting the correct team. I think perhaps Flutter does have a saved file somewhere with these old default c

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change the default one that gets used as I create a new project, here's what worked for me:
1-Removing old certificate from keychain access
2-Adding new one
3-Restarting terminal session and creating a new project

ps: other steps that might be needed as well:
Sign out of old account on Xcode and sign in with the new one